# Why the address of pointer of an Array is the same of the data stored in that pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If you try that piece of code

```
#include<stdio.h> int main() { 


// Pointer to an integer 
int *p;  

// Pointer to an array of 5 integers 
int (*ptr)[5];  
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };

// Points to 0th element of the arr. 


// Points to the whole array arr. 
ptr = &arr;  

printf("p = %p, address of P = %p\n", p, &p); 
return 0; }
```

You will get something like `p = 0x7fff8e9b4370, P address = 0x7fff8e9b4340`
which means the address of pointer P is something and the data inside it is another

but if you try the same with the pointer of the array like this

```
#include<stdio.h> int main() { 


// Pointer to an integer 
int *p;  

// Pointer to an array of 5 integers 
int (*ptr)[5];  
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };

// Points to 0th element of the arr. 
p = arr; 

// Points to the whole array arr. 
ptr = &arr;  

printf("arr  = %p, arr address = %p\n", arr, &arr); 
return 0; }
```

You will get something like `arr = 0x7ffda0a04310, arr address = 0x7ffda0a04310`

So how come that a pointer data is the same the pointer Address in memory ?!! when we dereference the address of the arr pointer we should get the number 3 but as i understand from this is the address location `0x7ffda0a04310` in the memory has `0x7ffda0a04310` as a data

so where i am mistaken ?

Comment: What type do you think `int (*ptr)[5]` has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printing `p` means print `p`'s value, while `p`'s value is address of a integer number or address of an integer array.

printing `&p` means you print location of `p` on memory.

printing `arr` will show address of first element of the array, it is `&arr[0]`.

printing `&arr` will show location of arr on memory, it is also adress of first element of the array

So printing `p` will be different with printing `&p`.
`arr` and `&arr` are different types but it will give you the same result.

Comment: Are `&arr` and `arr` different types or the same as birdfreeyahoo says  they are different?

Comment: they are different type but they have the same value.

Comment: what is the type of each one of them ?

Comment: as I have mentioned in my answer. arr = &arr[0], it is address of the first element, means that address of single variable. In other hand, `&arr` is address of an array, means that adress if a consecutive numbers. In short, `arr` is `int*` and `arr` is same type with `int (*ptr)[5]`

Comment: you mean if array is 5 elements int 2 bytes each so &arr+1 will add 10 bytes to the address. i understand you well?

Comment: you mean `&arr` same type with `int (*ptr)[5]`?

Comment: yes, they are the same type. you can change value of `ptr` by add or sub with an integer, but not with `arr`

Comment: you mean i can write `ptr+1` but not `&arr+1` and `ptr` will jump 10 bytes
i got you well?

Comment: Example: ptr = ptr + 1; //yes, you can, it will jump 10byte as you said.
               arr  = ptr; //no, you can't, you can not change value of arr

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you use the symbol of an array, it actually evaluates to `&arr` (address to first element). So because of this `arr` and `&arr` are the same address (but not the same type!).

`arr` is of type `int*`

`&arr` is of type `int(*)[5]`

The difference is when you do pointer arithmetics. Incrementing `arr` will go to the address of the next element. So `*(arr+1)` is essentially the same as `arr[1]`. 
Incrementing `&arr` jumps over the whole array (incrementing a pointer always jumps the whole size of the type)

Comment: Thank u for the answer first of all
but what different type they are both ?can you pls tell me ?

Answer (score 1):

What you've discovered is that the address of an array is the same as the address of its first member.

When you use the array `arr` in an expression, in *most* cases it decays to a pointer to its first element.  So `arr` in an expression is equivalent to `&arr[0]`.  Since the members of `arr` have type `int`, the expression `&arr[0]` (and by extension `arr`) have type `int *`.

In some cases however this decay does *not* happen.  One of those is when an array is the operand of the `&` operator.  So the expression `&arr` has type `int (*)[5]`, i.e. a pointer to a array of `int` of size 5.

As for why the values of these two address are the same, it makes sense if you look at it:

```
                  arr 
                -------
0x7ffda0a04310  |  0  |
                -------
                |  0  |
                -------
                |  0  |
                -------
                |  0  |
                -------
0x7ffda0a04314  |  1  |
                -------
                |  1  |
                -------
                |  1  |
                -------
                |  1  |
                -------
                ...
```

Looking at this, you can see that the array itself and the array's first element start at the same address.

So `arr` (as an expression) has type `int *` while `&arr` has type `int(*)[5]`, but both have the same value.